# React Native Navigation - on Android modal fullscreen is not covering the whole screen

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

The modal `Stack.Screen` is behaving differently on iOS and Android. On iOS modal is covering the full screen, but on Android not. I would like to have a static header with some UI (burger etc.), that is present in all screens and I don't want to animate the same UI as `Stack.Screen` header every time I change the screen. To achieve this I have added a static header outside Stack.Navigator. Everything works as expected apart from modal screen. When I initialise modal screen I expect it to cover the whole screen - also the static header. That is true for iOS. However on Android the static header component is not covered. I guess it is due to the fact that my static header "lives" outside `Stack.Navigator`.
I have created snack, so check it out https://snack.expo.dev/@fjckls/fullscreen-modal-android-issue
How to implement the desired behaviour with static header? Thanks!

```
const Contacts = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Contacts</Text>
      <Button title="Show Modal" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Modal')} />
    </View>
  );
};
const About = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>About</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const Modal = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>This is fullscreen modal!!!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const MyStaticHeader = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: 60, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'orange' }}>
      <Text>MY STATIC HEADER!!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator>
      <TopTab.Screen name="Contacts" component={Contacts} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="About" component={About} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <StatusBar animated={true} backgroundColor="#61dafb" />
      <MyStaticHeader />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Modal"
            component={Modal}
            options={{ presentation: 'modal',animation: 'slide_from_bottom' }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

[image: Here on iOS everything as expected]

[image: On Android header is visible and above modal]

Comment: just replace modal with fullScreenModal

Comment: Hi, did just that and the same.... header is visible on Android. It seems that modal is only covering other screens that are children of <NavigationContainer>

Comment: OP - did you find any solution to this? I have exactly the same problem with a static header that is a sibling of a parent, but I want render a sub-stack covering the whole thing.